# How to specify jnlp codebase with javafx ant tasks?

Tags: java, javafx-2, jnlp

I am using [JavaFX ant tasks](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference001.htm) to generate the JNLP file. I found some Oracle documentation claiming that [fx:deploy accepts a codebase attribute](https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/packaging_improvements_in_jdk_7#5):

```
<fx:deploy width="600" height="400"  
              outdir="Samples"  
              codebase="http://localhost/codebaseTest"  
              outfile="TestApp">  
    .... 
</fx:deploy>
```

But this does not seem to work for me. Ant says:

```
fx:deploy doesn't support the "codebase" attribute
```

So the question is, how do I specify the codebase for the generated JNLP, when using JavaFX ant tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog mentions upcoming features in a preview version of Java 7u10.

It looks like the `fx:deploy` `codebase` feature didn't make it to the final release.  The codebase attribute is not [documented in the official reference for the released packager](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference001.htm#CIABIFCI).

The related feature tracker is [RT-23509 add ant task for defining codebase in jnlp](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-23509).  Looks like it is implemented in an upcoming release (JavaFX version 2.2.40, and JavaFX 8).

You can download a [Java 8 preview](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) which will contain the fix.  You may be able to use the packaging tools from the Java 8 preview to package a Java 7 app, I am not sure.

Comment: It seems the JIRA link requires login, is there a way to get a link that does not? Nice digging anyway, I'll accept this! I went for a workaround meanwhile, I'll post that as an alternative answer.

Comment: Yep, the JavaFX JIRA requires login, a little annoying, but it's an open system and anybody can sign up for an account at the login prompt, then immediately access the system after signup - it sure beats the current jdk bug tracking system if you've ever used that . . .

Answer (score 1):

See jewelsea's answer for the official solution. Meanwhile, I had to go for this workaround using ant tasks:

```
<fx:deploy ...
</fx:deploy>
<replaceregexp file="path/to.jnlp" match="&lt;jnlp" replace="&lt;jnlp codebase=&quot;${jnlp.codebase}&quot;" />
```

It basically just modifies the  tag of the generated JNLP, by adding the codebase attribute.